# React native debug js causes react navigation auth flow stuck on Authloading screen

Tags: react-native

I have implemented Auth Flow from React navigation [from here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow.html),

Everything works fine till now but When I start React native debugger using Debug JS Remotely and Hit Reload by pressing R two times, My application stuck on AuthLoading Screen.

Comment: Please help if anyone having solution of this problem please let me know

Comment: still, anyone didn't face this kind of problem.